# Updating object Linq'd from collection doesn't update the object in collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have two simple classes. One is called `UseCounter<T>` and is a simple container for other objects while holding some information about its use (how many times it's been already used and if it can be reused once again).

Then there is `Dispenser<T>`, which holds a collection of `UseConter<T>` and is used to get the right element from the collection and then update its information.

The trouble I have is in the Dispenser's `Get()` method. It should return the object with the lowest combination of `Count` and `TotalCount`, and then call `Increase()` method in order to increase count.

However, when I run this code, `Dispenser<T>` always returns the same element. It's like the Linq'd element wasn't a reference to the object, but its copy, so the `Increase()` method increases only the local object's properties, but not the one in the collection.

I am at loss here, because I have never encountered such a behaviour.

Here comes the code:

**UseCounter:**

```
public class UseCounter<T>
{
    public T Element { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public bool Useful { get; set; }

    public UseCounter(T element)
    {
        this.Element = element;
        this.Count = 0;
        this.TotalCount = 0;
        this.Useful = true;
    }

    public void IncreaseCounter()
    {
        this.Count++;
        this.TotalCount++;
    }

    public void DecreaseCounter()
    {
        if(this.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Count cannot be lower than 0!");
        }

        this.Count--;
    }
}
```

**Dispenser**:

```
private readonly object _elementLocker = new object();
    private IEnumerable<UseCounter<T>> _elements;

    public IEnumerable<T> Elements 
    {
        get { return _elements.Select(e => e.Element); }
    }

    public int FinishedCount 
    { 
        get
        {
            lock (_elementLocker)
            {
                return _elements.Where(e => e.Useful == false).Count();
            }
        } 
    }

    public int CurrentlyWorkingCount
    {
        get
        { 
            lock (_elementLocker)
            {
                return _elements.Where(e => e.Count > 0).Count();
            }
        }
    }

    public Dispenser(IEnumerable<T> elements)
    {
        this._elements = elements
            .Distinct()
            .Select(e => new UseCounter<T>(e));
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        lock(_elementLocker)
        {
            var lCount = _elements
                .Where(e => e.Useful == true)
                .Select(e => e.Count).Min();

            var lTCount = _elements
                .Where(e => e.Useful == true)
                .Where(e => e.Count == lCount)
                .Select(e => e.TotalCount).Min();

            var el = _elements
                .Where(e => e.Useful == true)
                .First(e => e.Count == lCount && e.TotalCount == lTCount);

            el.IncreaseCounter();

            return el.Element;
        }
    }

    public void Report(T element, bool successful)
    {
        lock(_elementLocker)
        {
            var el = _elements
                .First(e => e.Element == element);
            el.DecreaseCounter();

            if(el.Useful == true && successful == true)
            {
                el.Useful = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
this._elements = elements
    .Distinct()
    .Select(e => new UseCounter<T>(e));
```

This is lazy. Every time you iterate over `_elements`, it will go back to the original source data, find a distinct set, and then project that set onto a *new* sequence of `UseCounter` instances. Any changes you make to those instances are irrelevant to what happens when you next iterate over `_elements`.

If you're happy for the set of input elements to be "frozen" on construction, you can just materialize the query so it only executes once:

```
this._elements = elements
    .Distinct()
    .Select(e => new UseCounter<T>(e))
    .ToList();
```

Now every time you iterate over `elements`, you're iterating over the same sequence of references.